# Not working Title attribute for image tag?

Tags: html, firefox

I am facing bit strange problem with my application. I have an image

```
<img title="New (Alt+N)" alt="New (Alt+N)" src="images/icon_new.gif" tabindex="-1" id="Ax14490_image">
```

This code is found inspecting document withfirebug.

which is displaying properly but title is not coming on mouseover of that image. can any one help me out in this context.

I am using firefox 4.0 browser

Comment: It's working for me ... [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VbTxV/) ... maybe you have some JavaScript that is blocking it

Comment: Is that possible to block title attribute with Script?

Comment: Here's another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491106/not-working-title-attribute-for-image-tag/53808473#53808473

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone else finds this thread via a search, I was having the same problem as described by the original poster. Here's what turned out to be the cause, in my case.

My layout involved two div objects placed horizontally next to one another. One on the left, and the other on the right. The left div was set to have a width of 100%, although it's contents did not cover all of that space due to internal padding. the right div contained the img which was not triggering any mouse events (including the "title" attribute not working, but onMouseOver and onMouseOut also did not work.)

So this was due to z-ordering. The mouse events were instead being handled by the div object on the left, because it's 100% width encompassed the full browser window. Since the left div had a "position" attribute of "absolute", it could legally have it's z-value set, and so I set its z-value to "-1". This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works for me too.

However, here is a useful guide to the correct usage of both the alt and title tags:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200412/the_alt_and_title_attributes/

Answer (score 1):

Too Late..But Try This...This is working for me

```
<img src="images/icon_new.gif" title="New (Alt+N)" tabindex="-1" id="Ax14490_image">
```

src tag at the first.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm way late to the party but things are radically different today (Dec. 2018) than they were when this post was created (Jun. 2011).

In case someone is having this problem with images not showing the tooltip of the `title=""` attribute, well, make sure you are not testing in Responsive Mode.

The `title=""` attribute obviously isn't going to work because Responsive Mode in browsers, at least in Firefox and Chrome, emulate touchscreen devices and the `title=""` attribute only works with a mouse pointer.

Yep, I know what you're thinking…