# is there a way to make title= attribute work on Chrome?

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, title

```
<span title="Hover text">Hello World</span>
```

In Firefox, that will display a tooltip with "Hover text" but in Chrome, you get nothing. Any way to fix this with HTML/CSS or is another scripting language required?

Comment: Post your view code maybe we can help you if you still didn't figure it out

Comment: it's Google's never ending beta land attitude, they output versions so fast, they do not have time to test it, tootips worked fine in pre- 31.0.1626.1 dev-m Aura, now they are dead (they work fine in other browsers) - same way non-flash YouTube movies cut short, when playing - when I installed earlier chrome for test. both tooltips and non-flash movies started to work - looks like Chrome devs just like keeping us on our toes - no more to it - use jquery ui tips to be on a safe side, unless you need this w/out JS

Comment: chromium 34 is also ignoring title attributes

Comment: still broken in chrome version "39.0.2171.71 m" for me.

Comment: Test: http://jsfiddle.net/qdomqcsx/ (still broken on 39.0.2171.95 m)

Comment: Still seems to be broken in 41.0.2272.101 m. But as I can observe it sometimes works but other times it doesn't. I don't know how to repro the problem.

Comment: Here's another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491106/not-working-title-attribute-for-image-tag/53808473#53808473

Answer (score 7):

`title="hover text"` is the way chrome works. Are you sure you don't have something else (maybe a div with no content) overtop of the span text?

Answer (score 4):

It works for me with only title.

You should use both `alt="Hover text"` and `title="Hover text"`

Comment: @zeroality, you must have misunderstood something. The `alt` attribute is invalid and ignored by browsers in a `span` element. Possibly you added it in a way that accidentally changed something else on the page.

Comment: See also http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2010/01/alt-and-title-content-display-in-popular-browsers/

Comment: ALT is only applicable to <img> tags. The content of the Alt attribute is only shown if the image does not load, at-least that's the way it's suppose to work - some old versions of IE display it if there is no title tag on an image. Either way ALT is not applicable to a <span>

Answer (score 2):

Though this is a really old post i've seen no answer. I've had the same sort problem and for me the problem was that the element was behind another. I've moved it up using z-index and that solved it.

Comment: Can you please bring a more elaborate answer? Refer [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

If you come here from Google looking for an answer about glitches in the title attribute using Chromium under linux. Then you can be interested in [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=442111) which is apparently fixed in latest versions

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue with "title" tooltip defined on a div not showing. 
In my case it wasn't a browser-specific thing, but I thought I'll post it here anyway...

I solved it by defining a higher z-index.

Comment: You can't assign a z-index to a `title` *attribute*.