# Adding a tooltip to an input box

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I am using the CSS.Tooltips library to try an get a tooltip to show up on an input tag.  I can get it to work on a p tag but not an input tag.  Any ideas?

Here is link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cwlanca/BumU5/1/

**Code**

```css
[data-tip] {
  position:relative;

}
[data-tip]:before {
  content:'';
  /* hides the tooltip when not hovered */
  display:none;
  content:'';
  display:none;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1a1a1a;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:35px;
  z-index:8;
  font-size:0;
  line-height:0;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:35px;
  z-index:8;
  font-size:0;
  line-height:0;
  width:0;
  height:0;
}
[data-tip]:after {
  display:none;
  content:attr(data-tip);
  position:absolute;
  top:35px;
  left:0px;
  padding:5px 8px;
  background:#1a1a1a;
  color:#fff;
  z-index:9;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  height:18px;
  line-height:18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  word-wrap:normal;
}
[data-tip]:hover:before,
[data-tip]:hover:after {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<p data-tip="This is the text of the tooltip">This is a paragraph of text that has a tooltip.</p>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<input data-tip="This is the text of the tooltip" value="44"/>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, it work for all input type that aren't textbox (checkboxes, radio,...)

There is a quick workaround that will work.

```
<div data-tip="This is the text of the tooltip2">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="44"/>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BumU5/3/)

Comment: This appears to break if you add the HTML 5 "required" attribute to the input field. When you hover over the input field, the tooltip is displayed as expected, but then is partially overwritten by the browser supplied "Please fill out this field" tooltip

Comment: It's not a bug - the tooltip css relies on `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors which do not work on input elements. It needs to be a container so the pseudo elements can be appended.

Comment: I can see that this works in the JsFiddle, but for some reason it doesn't work for me at all... any idea what I should pay attention to?

Comment: <input tip="Tip!" type="text"/> works in current browsers. No more need for the div

Comment: I had the need for a disappearing tooltip. With a bit of JavaScript and a small update to the JsFiddle i was able to achieve this. if anyone is interested i attached it here https://jsfiddle.net/e4qo6dmz/

Answer (score 218):

I know this is a question regarding the CSS.Tooltips library. However, for anyone else came here resulting from google search "tooltip for input box" like I did, here is the simplest way:

```
<input title="This is the text of the tooltip" value="44"/>
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug in some of the older chrome versions. Try to use alt and title together. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391327/is-there-a-way-to-make-title-attribute-work-on-chrome

Comment: Note that for narrow input types (such as radio) this obviously only appears when hovering over the actual radio button, not over the associated legend which is not what your user might expect

Answer (score 7):

```
<input type="name" placeholder="First Name" title="First Name" />
```

`title="First Name"` solves my proble. it worked with bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from HTML 5 data-tip You can use css also for making a totally customizable tooltip to be used anywhere throughout your markup.

```css
/* ToolTip classses */ 
.tooltip {
    display: inline-block;    
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    margin-left:9px;
    width : 320px;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top : -15px; 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    right: 100%;  
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #aeaeae transparent transparent;
}


.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <input type="text" />
  <span class="tooltiptext">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for input type. Please look the question carefully.

Comment: this is just the styling I have given, you can tweek the css bit for your own usage. :)

Comment: When scrolling down on a large page, you cant see the tooltip anymore.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bootstrap (I am using version 4.0), feel free to try the following code.

```
<input data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="This is the text of the tooltip" value="44"/>
```

`data-placement` can be *top, right, bottom* or *left*

Comment: in order for this to work you must enable tooltips via `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` after the document is ready