# Having trouble with custom HTML Helper, CSS, and data attributes

Tags: css, html

I've written a custom helper:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxForWithTooltip<Tmodel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<Tmodel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<Tmodel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null, string tooltip = "")
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        IDictionary<string, object> attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metaData.Description))
        {
            attributes.Add("title", metaData.Description);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tooltip))
        {
            attributes.Add("data-tooltip", tooltip);
        }
        if (attributes.ContainsKey("style"))
        {
            var val = attributes["style"];
            attributes["style"] = val + ";border-radius: 6px;";
        }
        else
        {
            attributes.Add("style", "border-radius: 6px;");
        }
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);
    }
```

And the CSS, which I got from [here][1].  This works great when you assign the data-tooltip to a button or an "a" or "li" element.  But not to an input or TextBoxFor.  I see the data-tooltip attribute in the page source but it apparently does not trigger the CSS to show the tooltip.  Does anyone have an idea why?

Actually what I did was this:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxForWithTooltip<Tmodel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<Tmodel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<Tmodel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null, string tooltip = "")
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        if (attributes.ContainsKey("style"))
        {
            var val = attributes["style"];
            attributes["style"] = val + ";border-radius: 6px;";
        }
        else
        {
            attributes.Add("style", "border-radius: 6px;");
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("<div data-tooltip='" + tooltip + "'>" + htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes) + "</div>");
    }
```

I embedded the html within the DIV to get the tooltip.

Comment: that is because the CSS uses `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements which do not apply to replaced elements such as `input` and `textarea` (*same goes for `img`,`select` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element for more*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible duplicate of [Adding a tooltip to an input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480010/adding-a-tooltip-to-an-input-box) though there was no conclusive answer back in 2013 when this question was asked There are a couple of workarounds there.

It seems that it may be that the tooltip is not possible over inputs. In which case wrap the input in an `<a>` as so:

```
<a href="#" alt="Please enter username" class="tooltip">
    <input id="txtUsername" type="text" />
</a>
```

Taken from a longer explanation here

https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1529/simple-tooltip-using-html-css

with more details of the approach but excluding inputs here

https://davidwalsh.name/css-attr-content-tooltips

Comment: Is it possible for the html helper to return the div tag with the text box inside it?