# How to force "title" attribute to show even when is "<input>" active (clicked)

Tags: html, css, input, css-transitions

For example :

```html
<input type="text" title="Here is my title"  value="smth"/>
```

if you just mouseover (without clicking) for 2 second, the `title` will show up.
But how to force the `title` to show up even if user clicks (doesnt wait for 2 seconds) in text field?

**NOTES:**

1) I am interested in pure approach, without libraries.

2) I am not interested in adding extra `<html>` elements, because there [is solution for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37983831/2377343).

Comment: You may want to look into the `placeholder` attribute. This shows a greyed-out description in the input field until actual text is entered.

Comment: @frececroka thanks, I am not about `placeholder` i know that ; )

Comment: since this a behaviour of the browser you need to use a js tooltip that shows the same text

Comment: you may need to have a javascript Tooltip library.

Comment: Could anyone say why downvoted?

Comment: http://pauljadam.com/demos/title-keyboard.html

Answer (score 2):

Without library:

```css
input[type=text] + span {
  display: none;
}
input[type=text]:focus + span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" title="Here is my title"  value="smth"/> <span>Here is my title</span>
```

Using script to get the title

```js
function insertAfter(el, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(el, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

window.addEventListener("load",() => {
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]").forEach(inp => {
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = inp.getAttribute("title");
    insertAfter(span, inp);
  })
})
```

```css
input[type=text] + span {
  display: none;
}
input[type=text]:focus + span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" title="Here is my title 1"  value="smth"/><br/>
<input type="text" title="Here is my title 2"  value="smth"/><br/>
<input type="text" title="Here is my title 3"  value="smth"/><br/>
```

Comment: Make since to have like this, +1!

Comment: well, thanks for answer, just i didnt wanted to add extra html elements... however, upvoted answer.... (is not there any JS/prototype script that might change browser property/behavior with regard to titles? at least, cuted down 2 second to 0.2 sec)

Comment: @T.Todua My second version does not need extra HTML in the markup. It generates the span from the input. There is no way to change the built-in delay in title showing