# See "real" commit date / time in github (hour/day)

Tags: git, date, github, commit

Is there a way to see the date of a commit in github, with day/hour precision? Older commits appear in a "human readable" format, such as "2 years ago" instead of showing the actual date.

[image: old github commit]

If it's not possible to see the actual date on github, is there a easier workaround than `git clone`?

Answer (score 415, accepted):

Hover your mouse over the `2 years ago` and you'll get the timestamp.

Comment: I had no idea you could do this...this helped me out. But I wonder, is there a git command you can enter that'll display this information if you pass in the commit hash?

Comment: I agree, the solution is a setting to show the date.  "2 hours ago" is just terrible in my opinion.  Bitbucket does the same. It seems harder to do this - anyone know WHY both choose to show this duration?

Comment: How do you "hover over" anything when you're using a phone?

Comment: This shows the author date, not the commit date.

Answer (score 13):

The real date does not appear for me upon hovering "2 years ago", despite the text being wrapped by a `<time>` element with an iso value under its `datetime` attribute.

If all else fails, like it did for me, try inspecting the text.

Sample element:

`<time datetime="2015-01-22T20:48:13Z" is="relative-time" title="Jan 22, 2015, 2:48 PM CST">7 days ago</time>`

Comment: Has nothing to do with their end or time element or anything like that. It's you and your browser. A title attr is displayed by browsers as a tooltip when you hover. No fancy js, no css, nothing. Some people have reported issues with chrome and title attr see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314758/html-title-attribute-not-showing-as-tooltip-in-chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391327/is-there-a-way-to-make-title-attribute-work-on-chrome

Comment: @dalore - Bad site design then still.  An author of an HTML document should not make assumptions about how any element is displayed by any particular browser.

Answer (score 9):

you can just use this js bookmark:

```
javascript:(function() { 
        var relativeTimeElements = window.document.querySelectorAll("relative time");
        relativeTimeElements.forEach(function(timeElement){
        timeElement.innerHTML = timeElement.innerHTML +" -- "+ timeElement.title;
        })
    }()
)
```

https://gist.github.com/PhilippGrulich/7051832b344d4cbd30fbfd68524baa38

It adds just the correct time:
Like this:
committed 21 hours ago -- 15. Feb. 2017, 15:49 MEZ

Comment: Yours didnt work for me, so I wrote this and it worked; +1 for the inspiration `javascript:(function() { var el = document.createElement('div'); document.body.prepend(el); el.innerHTML  = document.getElementsByTagName('relative-time')[0].getAttribute('title');}() )`

Answer (score 7):

Update 2021: a bookmarklet remains the only option on GitHub.
See for instance "[Displaying Real Commit Times in GitHub](https://justinnoel.dev/2020/11/21/displaying-real-times-in-github/)" from [Justin Noel](https://twitter.com/JustinNoelDev)

```js
javascript:(function() {    
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  var sheet = style.sheet;
  sheet.addRule('time-ago:before,relative-time:before', 'content: attr(title);display: block;font-size: 0.5rem;');  
})()
```

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/card_img/1432824610794393602/CE26XtQw?format=jpg&name=small]

---

This contrasts with [GitLab 14.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/07/22/gitlab-14-1-released/#user-setting-to-display-absolute-times) (July 2021)

> ### User setting to display absolute times
>
> GitLab displays relative times (for example, 30 minutes ago) in a lot of places.
>
> **You can now change your user profile preferences to display absolute times instead, for example, ‘`May 18, 2021, 3:57 PM`’**.
>
> Absolute times respect your browser settings and format dates and times based on your preferred locales, for example, British English over US English.
>
> This new display option gives more information at a glance for users that need it for workflows like correlating actions in GitLab to external systems.
>
> [image: dd GitHub]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/preferences.html#time-preferences) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14560).

Comment: Hi, this is what worked for me!  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I tried @odony's TamperMonkey/Greasemonkey script on Chrome but couldn't get it to work. `detachCallback()` wasn't recognized. So instead of detaching any callbacks, I simply replaced the `<relative-time>` node.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Github: always show absolute times
// @match        https://github.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll("relative-time").forEach(function(el) {
        var parent = el.parentNode;
        var timestamp = el.title;
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = timestamp;
        parent.removeChild(el);
        parent.appendChild(span);
    });
})();
```

Sorry I haven't tested this with other browser, but since this is basic javascript, it should just work. :)

Answer (score 4):

With a user stylesheet plugin (I'm using stylebot in chrome)

```css
time {
  font-size: 0;
}
time:after {
    content: attr(data-original-title);
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a way to display the date/time permanently without hovering (e.g. for screenshots), the above Javascript-based solutions do not match the latest Github HTML (see comments). And they did not take into account the fact that the timestamps are auto-updated based on a timer (*"X minutes ago"* has to change every minute), so they will periodically reappear.

The following script seems to work on Github as of 2020-01-27:

```js
(function() {
    var els = window.document.querySelectorAll("time-ago,relative-time");
    els.forEach(function(el) {
        el.innerHTML = "on " + el.getFormattedTitle(); // original timestamp
        el.disconnectedCallback(); // stop auto-updates
    });
})();
```

You can make this a **bookmarklet** by prefixing the code with `javascript:` as in the other JS-based solution.

And if you want to make this a **permanent** fix, you can save this as a TamperMonkey/Greasemonkey script, as follows:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Github: always show absolute times
// @match        https://github.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var els = window.document.querySelectorAll("time-ago,relative-time");
        els.forEach(function(el) {
            el.innerHTML += ' <span class="text-small">(' + el.title + ')</span>'; // set original timestamp
            el.disconnectedCallback(); // stop auto-updates
        });
    }, 100); // YMMV, experiment with the timeout
})();
```

That's not very pretty but it seems to do the job.

Comment: Love that you included it as tampermonkey/greasemonkey script, makes this more of an actual solution

Comment: Awesome! For me, I had to remove the comments from the code for it to work as a bookmarklet. Here's the full thing: `javascript:(function() { var els = window.document.querySelectorAll("time-ago,relative-time");    els.forEach(function(el) { el.innerHTML = "on " + el.getFormattedTitle();  
 el.disconnectedCallback();});})();`

Answer (score 0):

With gitlab 10 I used this to add the tooltip title to the element as standard text:

```
javascript:(function() { 
  var relativeTimeElements = window.document.querySelectorAll("time");
  relativeTimeElements.forEach(function(timeElement){
    timeElement.innerHTML = timeElement.innerHTML +" -- "+ timeElement.getAttribute('data-original-title');
  })
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Booklets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) are a convenient way to toggle the date time format on and off. Here's one that I use:

```
javascript: (() => {
  let style = document.querySelector('#replace-relative-time');

  if (style) return style.remove();

  style = document.createElement('style');
  style.setAttribute('id', 'replace-relative-time');
  document.head.appendChild(style);

  style.sheet.insertRule(`
        :not([role=gridcell]) > relative-time {
            display: inline-flex;
        flex-direction: row;
            visibility: hidden;
            text-indent: -1000px;
        }
    `);

  style.sheet.insertRule(`
        :not([role=gridcell]) time-ago:after, :not([role=gridcell]) > relative-time:after {
            content: attr(title);
            display: block;
            visibility: visible;
            text-indent: 0;
        }
    `);
})();
```

Alternatively, if you'd like this behaviour to persist across multiple tabs, you could take this snippet and put it into a chrome extension that runs on any specified pages.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one for Gogs

```
javascript:(function() {
     var items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span,relative-time'));  items.forEach(function(item) {    item.innerText = item.getAttribute('data-content');    item.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';    item.style.padding = '5px';    item.style.color = '#333';    item.style.fontWeight = 'bold';  });})()
```