# Any way in Github.com to see the exact time for a commit or release

Tags: github

I'm using github for students to submit a programming assignment. And I have a strict deadline for submission and I would like to be able to check the time that their release was submitted.

Unfortunately, github only reports how many *days ago* a release or commit was made. Is there any (quick) way to get the exact time?

Comment: I wasn't sure this was the correct SE site for the question, but looking at the number of 'github' taged q's on programmers.se & webapps.se, convinced me that this was the place for qithub quries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See "real" commit date in github (hour/day)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500411/see-real-commit-date-in-github-hour-day)

Comment: @ken, I usually git clone the students' repositories at exactly SUBMISSION_TIME + 1 min. and these are the versions that get checked.

Comment: To further add to these answers, I've included screenshots to show exactly where to hover. **Github**
[![Screenshot of hovering over 'xx ago' label which shows exact time of commit via tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlg1p.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlg1p.png) **Github Desktop**
[![Screenshot of hovering over 'xx ago' label in Github desktop which shows exact time of commit via tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnE7e.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnE7e.png)

Comment: See this answer for 2022 [Bookmarkelet solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079928/2704776)

Answer (score 209, accepted):

If you move your mouse over the `xx minutes|hours\... ago` label, a tooltip will be displayed showing the UTC time the commit was created at.

Keep in mind that Git history can be rewritten (see **[git commit --amend](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)** or **[git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)** commands for instance) and that this displayed time shouldn't  be considered as solid proof.

Comment: Perfect! Good advice about the potential to re-write history. Thanks

Comment: But WHY, oh WHY?  Can't they have an option to show the date and time.  It's all I ever want to see.

Comment: @DanielWilliams https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/17702

Answer (score 7):

Well I'm jumping into this WAAAYY late, but I wanted to add a note about this particular use case.

[nulltoken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21701590/2158648) is absolutely right about the possibility of the times being modified. To circumvent this, I would make use of tags. Slap together a simple script that would pull the branch at the cutoff point, tag it (using an annotated tag), and then push the tag up to github. This gives you a snapshot of the branch at that particular time, stamped the time that the tag was cut AND the name of the tagger. That last part is particularly useful for students who think they are crafty.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Cheers!

Comment: Better late than never! I'm always open to good ideas... That actually might work! What happens if a student re-tags using the same tag?

Comment: Without testing it myself, I would expect the student's name to show up as the tagger (if they created an annotated tag) or the tagger's name to disappear (if they used a simple tag). That is worth playing around with though. I'm also not sure if it is possible to lock users out of pushing tags.