# Why are title attributes in images not displaying as tooltips

Tags: html, image, tags, title

I have a problem getting the title attribute to popup in an image tag. The page in question is at http://design.wildsandwebdesign.co.uk/technical/using-delphi-with-mysql-1.php. There are 4 images all with text in the title and alt attributes. None of the titles pop up in Firefox 19.0.2 or in Chrome or Opera running in WinXP but they do in IE8 (oops!). The W3C validator says the page is clean.

My site has many other pages where the title attribute in an image does work, and just a couple with the same problem. I tried cranking up the z-index for the images but no luck. It seems to happen when there are 3] images on the page, but there are other pages with 3 or 4 images where it DOES work. I simply cannot figure it out.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: Take the images out of the H elements.

Comment: Here's another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491106/not-working-title-attribute-for-image-tag/53808473#53808473

Answer (score 0):

Because your images are overlapped by your `p` elements

[image]

Remove the `width` and `position` properties from your `p` tags, and use `margin`'s and `padding`'s instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the images aren't seen to be hovered over, because the `p` elements overlay them.

You can get the tooltip to show if you hover over the leftmost few pixels of the first image.

Comment: Er yes, thats a bit obvious. But these are inline images so why is it happening? It works properly on the next page for instance. I note that (1) you get the tooltip if you hover in line with a paragraph break in the text alongside, (2) if I float the image left after a <p> with a para break in text to the right half way down the image, the tooltip is ok with the cursor in line with the 1st para, but not the second para!!! (3) if I put a link around the image the hover sees and  clicking goes to the link yet the tooltip wont appear. However the important thing is - how do I fix it.

Comment: Maybe I didnt put enough info in there but to me its clear what is (or isnt) happening, but the question is why? And it s not a bizarre thing to want to do. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know you don't answer your own question but in the end I found the answer myself and I am a bit disappointed that some answers missed the point. Yes it was clear the text was "in front of the image". Frankly I would think that was obvious and took it for a given. My mistake. However, here's the thing. The browser knows when it sees this construct that it has to put the following text to the side, right or left, of the image and it does that. Yet it ignores the fact that it is alongside the image and prevents the tooltip showing. The browser also knows where the cursor is, or it couldn't do this in the first place.

Maybe this stems from W3C having defined how browsers deal with inline images without thinking it through. But in the end once I figured out "why" it was happening it was easy to figure out an answer. Even though I had to do it myself.

Jim

Comment: This happens where any inline image projects outside its containing block, if the image is in a p block, the hover disappears after the end of that p block. It has nothing to do with the next p block “overlaying” the image – because it doesn't! Try implementing a hover over the text in the second p block. It will be where it should be, over the text but not the image. Jim