# html title attribute not showing as tooltip in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

Recently updated my Google Chrome to version 32.0.1700.76 m and it looks like tooltips have stopped appearing over html elements with the 'title' attribute set.

`<span alt="Testing" title="Testing">hhh</span>`

Here is an example jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ricksuggs/cDhEL/

I thought it was an HTML standard, it is still working in Firefox, anyone else experiencing the issue?

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 your code seems to be working for me.

Comment: I am using Version Chrome Version 32.0.1700.77 and your code works

Comment: Restarted my PC and the tooltip started appearing again.. oh well.

Comment: I'm having this issue right now on  33.0.1750.154 m. No idea why. Tried restarting Chrome to no avail. Maybe a reboot will do it.

Comment: Yeah, stopped working for me as well in: Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153
If a restart of chrome fixes it, I'll mention in an additional comment.

Comment: Restart to chrome fixed it on the example jsFiddle and the page that I originally had the problem on.  So worth a try at least.

Comment: I left my mouse still over the span for a long time and the title text appeared. It was very, very slow in showing. I updated chrome from 44 something to 45.0.2454.85, and the problem was resolved. Mostly, I just thought it was good to note that the problem might be a problem in slowness and not a problem with the title text not working at all. If you leave your mouse still for a whole minute, does the title text show? Mine showed in probably 20 seconds.

Comment: Here's another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491106/not-working-title-attribute-for-image-tag/53808473#53808473

Comment: Still happening in Nov 2019. Page refresh solved it .... grrr!

Answer (score 5):

Version 32.0.1700.76 m works fine for me. Have you tried just clearing your Chrome browser cache to make sure it's not a caching issue?

Comment: It was a caching issue for me.  Ctrl+F5 got it working.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this is an old bug that have pop with version 32.0.1700 and is still present in v55 on some system such as mine too.

If you encounter this bug. Please go to http://download1.srware.net/old/iron/win/portable to test version 31 then 32. If you find out it works with v31 but it doesn't with v32, please report it in the chromium bug tracker [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389380). Specify your setup sharing a link provided by [DriversCloud.com](http://www.driverscloud.com/en/start) to help dev to fix it. They need feedback and details.